# How to move an object to a different render layer?

Tags: rendering, render-layers, layers

I am wondering how to move something to another render layer.

I see the render layers next to where it says *Global*, but how do I switch my objects over to another render layer?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/16239/599, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15909/599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With <kbd>M</kbd>, i.e. move them between viewport layers:

[image]

See my [answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15915/599) for more detail.

*<sub>Thanks to this question, I found and reported [a regression](https://developer.blender.org/T45162) in blender's handling of view specific and scene specific layers.</sub>*